# How to download and display an image from a link to DataGridView in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, image

I have a program that gets data from a MySQL database with C#. One of the columns that's selected is an image column, which contains a url that points to an image. I want to use my C# to download that image then display it to a DataGridView. How do I do this?

Comment: So the question is *"How to display an image"* or *"How to download an image"* ?

Comment: @Jim How to download then display an image.